# Export the data from a Mongo DB database in a CSV

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs, json2csv

I have a project in Node JS in which I want to export the data contained in the database in `Mongo DB` in a CSV file through a button in the view (`index.ejs`).
I am using `mongoose` for the connection to the database and to export the data to the CSV I am trying to use `json-2-csv`.

In the button I have added a url to be able to call that url through the button and that the json-2-csv function responds to that url but I don't know how to do it or if it is the best way.

This is my `app.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const json2csv = require("json2csv").Parser;
const userModel = require('./models/users');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/export/csv', async (req, res) => {
  await userModel.find((err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const json2csvParser = new json2csv({ header: true });
      const csvData = json2csvParser.parse(data);
      fs.writeFile("users.csv", csvData, function(error) {
          if (error) throw error;
          console.log("Write to bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv successfully!");
      });
      
  });
});
```

This is the `button`:

```
<form action="/export/csv" mehotd="GET">
    <button id="export-csv">Export CSV</button>
</form>
```

Comment: First, you need to have a DB connection established and need to have data in the DB. The way you did is fine so where are you stuck can you explain more?

Comment: @kedarsedai I do not know where to put the function if in the app.js or in the controller nor do I know how to import the connection to the database. And also, what I'm trying to do is call it from the button but I can't do it either, I don't know how to add to that function that responds to that url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve all these things in your single file `app.js` file. We need to have `json2csv` module because this `module` has the `parser` class so that we can use `parse()` method to get the `CSV` format data as `String`. Here `lean` options tell mongoose to skip instantiating a full `Mongoose document` and just give you the `Plain Old JavaScript Object` `POJO`. And also I have used `username` and `password` as `documents` so change it accordingly.

```
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
//You need to have some documents into your DB first 
const Collection = require('your/Modal Path');
const Json2csvParser = require("json2csv").Parser;
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Templating Engine Ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

//Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

//MONGO DB CONNECTION 
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/users';
mongoose.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully Established Connection with MongoDB')
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Failed to Establish Connection with MongoDB with Error: ' + err);
        process.exit();
    });

app.get('/export/csv', async (req, res) => {
    await Collection.find({}).lean().exec((err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const csvFields = ['_id', 'username', 'password']
        console.log(csvFields);
        const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({
            csvFields
        });
        const csvData = json2csvParser.parse(data);
        fs.writeFile("bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv", csvData, function(error) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log("Write to bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv successfully!");
        });
        res.send('File downloaded Successfully')
    });
});

//HOME route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home.ejs');
});

//listening to the PORT Number 
app.listen(port, console.log(`Server is running at ${port}`));
```

So, this is how your `app.js` file will look like. And also create a `home.ejs` file inside `views directory` like `views/home.ejs`. and add the below code:

```
<form action="/export/csv" mehotd="GET">
    <button id="export-csv">Export CSV</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have several problems: a csv is downloaded in the root folder of the project but it does not contain the data of the database, it only contains the data type and the name of the field. Another problem I have is that when downloading it the process does not end I do not know how to finish it. I have updated the question with the current code.

Comment: Ok now if it works, great thanks. Another question I have now, is it possible to change the destination folder, for example, that the file is downloaded in the Downloads folder and that the downloaded symbol appears in the browser?

Comment: yes, of course you can change the `destination` folder like `fs.writeFile("C:/folder/bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv", csvData, function(err) { ..... `

Comment: Ok thanks it works great. Could you help me in another question that I have open 'Handle errors in Node JS in the data model'. What I am trying is to show errors in the input form, for example, if in the age field I insert a String that will show me an error and the form is restarted. I've searched but can't find anything on this with Node JS and I'm pretty new.

Comment: do you mean if the user inputs age that is of string which needs to be in integer then you need to show an error like (age should be in number )?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if that is possible to show the error and restart the form.

Comment: you can achieve this from the `mongoose validation` later showing message in the `ejs` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html